# svn backup, delete and restore up to date repo

Tags: svn, backup

ref 
http://www.thecrumb.com/2006/08/17/subversion-hotcopy-backup-scripts/

```
@ECHO OFF
REM     will hotcopy your repo to My Documents
REM    this will delete the existing dir and create it again
REM    you could use this script with a scheduled task for backup


SET REPODIR=E:\Repositories\Android1
SET REPOBACKUP="C:\2

ECHO ==================================
ECHO        PROCESSING BACKUP ...
ECHO  This may take some time depending
ECHO     on the size of your repository!
ECHO ==================================

IF EXISTS RMDIR %REPOBACKUP% /S/Q

svnadmin hotcopy %REPODIR% %REPOBACKUP%

ECHO         BACKUP COMPLETED!
```

Basically, I have created a repository and I have used `svnadmin hotcopy` which appears to work. Can anyone explain in an easy way how to firstly after the hotcopy remove the copy and create an up to date copy of the repo which will obviously change the last updated time.

I cant see where I'm going wrong with this script, all my paths are correct. I'm using Windows.

Comment: apologies this is my current script ref http://www.thecrumb.com/2006/08/17/subversion-hotcopy-backup-scripts/                                                            
@ECHO OFF
SET REPODIR=E:\Repositories\Android1
SET REPOBACKUP="C:\2

RMDIR %REPOBACKUP%
svnadmin hotcopy %REPODIR% %REPOBACKUP%

ECHO         BACKUP COMPLETED!

Comment: you should edit your question (insert your current script).